# android - save to DB when activity ends and load in another activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

I would like to do this:
From activity A start activity B. In activity B before it ends (when I press home or back button - I use "protected void onStop()" method), save data to DB (sqlite).
And now I am back in activity A and I would like to reload data from DB (I use "protected void onRestart()" method). But there is my problem - when I load data from DB, I get old data (not new data, that was saved before activity B was ended).

Can you help me, where can be problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that onRestart on activity A may be called before onStop on activity B. Yopu can put a Log.d() just to check.

If this is the case, you can move the save to DB on activity B to the onPause() instead od onStop() and the issue will be fixed.